# HTML/JQuery/CSS: How to submit old checkbox value to server; while displaying checkbox disabled and unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Current Functionality:**
5 Checkboxes and Drop down

On Selection of a value in Drop down; Checkboxes enables and Disables

When enables, end user selected value and when disabled the value remained selected in disabled format.

[image]

**Requirement**

1) User do not want to loose value.

2)User want when it is disabled it should be unchecked

What is best design?

Shall it be saved in hidden checkboxes and data shall move to and fro in JQuery? 
or is there any better way to do it?

Current Code:

```
    if ($("#dropdown").val() === 'Val1' || $("#dropdown").val() === 'val2') {
       $(".checkboxes5").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
       $(".checkboxes5").prop("disabled", true); 
    }
```

Comment: please add your current code as well?

Comment: Are you asking about the best way to do it or do you have code samples? You're going to need to provide code samples, so we can assist, the platform doesn't write code for you.

Comment: You could put all of this into an event listener function, using `$(this)` and set your checked/unchecked and disabled logic around which selection has been made. `$(this).attr("disabled", true);` / `$(this).removeAttr("disabled");` and `$(this).value();` for the selected value. If `.attr()` and `removeAttr()` doesn't work, try `.prop()` and `.removeProp()` instead. Might wanna look up some docs. As for saving old value etc. it depends of what logic you are running with. If you are storing old values into the database, then you shouldn't need hidden checkboxes?

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. The values are stored in database but on click of submit button whatsoever is on front end gets updated in database. So if checkbox got unselected during disabled; it is mapped to entity due to which the old value could never be get. So we need to handle it on front end using some tweak

Comment: If you want, you could pair the logic with AJAX and use session variables for the *old* slections. That way, you are not using database logic for old values, but still have access to them during your process. Then all you need is to construct your logic around the selections themselves. I don't know if this makes sense to you, but I'm having a little trouble understanding what you meant by your last comment.

Comment: @Martin: I am using hidden Textbox with Semicolon separated values for all old checked values. Everytime when i click submit i will repopulate it from Textbox. On Page load, i will again populate hidden textbox from Checked values i get from database. To Front end user, i will mark unchecked on page load and on submit i will mark checked before submit. What do you think about that? (User just want to not to mark check on disabled fields.)